# AngularJS pass request directly to backend

Tags: angularjs

I think I've missed something but I have problem with implementing for example users activation process with use of links sent to users' e-mails.

I have page for signing up. After filling form request is sent to backend where some logic is done and also mail is sent to user's mailbox. In this mail there is activation link.
And here my problem starts - I want user to click that link and be moved to my page but I want to pass this token directly to backend to check its validity, activate account and at the end redirect user to login page.

How to implement that correctly?

That's my current routing configuration for AngularJS app:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'appController'
}).when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'userController'
}).when('/signup', {
    templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
    controller: 'userController'
}).when('/activate/:activationToken', {
    templateUrl: 'views/activate.html',
    controller: 'userController'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

That's my current backend routing configuration for node.js:

```
router.post('/users/login', userHelper.shouldNotBeLoggedIn, authentication.login);
router.post('/users/signup', userHelper.shouldNotBeLoggedIn, authentication.signup);
router.get('/users/logout', userHelper.shouldBeLoggedIn, authentication.logout);
router.get('/users/activate/:token', userHelper.shouldNotBeLoggedIn, authentication.activate);
```

Here is how I return data from backend to frontend:

```
if (err) {
    logger.error(util.inspect(err));
    res.status(403).json({message: err.code});
} else {
    res.status(200).json({message: 'accountActivated'});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a pure back-end URL + view that handles the account activation if the token is correct, then 302 redirect to a regular URL where the Angular app lives. If the token is incorrect, redirect to a URL that displays an error message.

---

Update:

In userController, when the URL matches the URL sent in the activation email (this may already exist at `/activate/:activationToken`), sent the token to your back-end like this:

```
// Make sure to inject $http and $routeParams in your controller.
$http.post('/users/activate/' + $routeParams.activationToken, {}).success(function(response) {
    console.log('Yay');
}).error(function(response) {
    console.error(response.data.message)
});
```

Comment: Do you have any example of configuration for Angular to support those 'pure backend URLs'?

Comment: Angular does not handle a pure back-end URL, it does not even come into the picture at this stage. You NEED to handle this on your server, then redirect back to your Angular app.

Comment: I've editted my question and added current routing configuration. If I open link with anything else in path than what's specified by `when` methods then I'm redirected to / by `otherwise` method.

Comment: You need to specify in your back-end that some URLs don't return an HTML page with the Angular app. Probably around the place in the back-end where you handle submitting the form. It would help if you added back-end URLs / views to your post.

Comment: I'm returning information from server with JSON and currently I don't have any place in server where I redirect user. Everything is done by Angular. I'll add backend routes configuration to my question in few seconds.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution that should match your existing back-end.